# How to fix "undefined method `key?'" in Rails with Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, grape-entity

I'm creating an API with Ruby on Rails. I use the gem 'grape' to provide the api to the consumer and 'spyke' to receive data from another api. I manipulate and enrich the data I receive from spyke and then pass it on to grape.
The problem is, that I receive an error: `undefined method key?`.

I've already checked the data I receive from spyke. The data seems ok (I don't receive an array, I get a Hash). I've printed it with `puts result` and `result.class` (result being the data spyke receives).
I've googled the error message `undefined method key?`. I tried all "solutions" provided by stackoverflow and other resources. None of them worked. I don't even know where the error is originated exactly.

```rb
resource :clusters do
  route_param :cluster_id do
    resource :stats do
      params do
        requires :node, type: String, desc: 'Node name.'
      end
      route_param :node do
        get do
          present StatsNode.where(cluster_id: params[:cluster_id], node: params[:node]), with: StatsNodeEntity
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know if this is important, but when I raise a string `raise 'test'` before the line `present StatsNode.where...`, the message `{"response_type":"error","response":"asdf"}` appears as the response. If I raise the string after the `present` line, then the initial error message appears.

The exact message reads: `{"response_type":"error","response":"undefined method key?' for [\"_nodes\", {\"total\"=\u003e1, \"successful\"=\u003e1, \"failed\"=\u003e0}]:Array"}`

I expect, that the api returns a json with the data and not with the error message.
Where is the error message from and how can I fix this problem?

**EDIT:**
I'm using:
- Ruby 2.5.5
- Rails 5.2.3
- spyke latest
- grape latest
- grape-entity latest

Comment: What version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Without having seen the code for `StatsNode` or `StatsNodeEntity`, I'm going to assume that the following is true:

- `StatsNode` is an ActiveRecord (or ActiveRecord-like) model
- `StatsNode.where()` returns an enumerable like ActiveRecord::Relation (with Array-like behavior)

Given that, the problem is most likely that your `where()` call is returning an array-like object when you expect it to return a single hash-like object. You can see that from the error:

```
{"response_type":"error","response":"undefined method key?' for [\"_nodes\", {\"total\"=\u003e1, \"successful\"=\u003e1, \"failed\"=\u003e0}]:Array"}
```

It's telling you you're trying to call `.key?` on an `Array` object.

The solution is probably to change this call:

```
StatsNode.where(cluster_id: params[:cluster_id], node: params[:node])
```

to:

```
StatsNode.find_by(cluster_id: params[:cluster_id], node: params[:node])
```

Comment: The StatsNode is not an ActiveRecord, it's inheriting from Spyke::Base. So theres no `StatsNode.find_by` available.

Comment: Then try `where().first`.

Comment: Then I recommend posting the StatsNodeEntity class.